# Unexplained out_of_range in string::substr

Tags: c++, g++

I have been getting a really annoying error about an std::out_of_range when calling substr. The exact error is

> terminate called after throwing an
>   instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>   what():  basic_string::substr

I'm absolutely sure that tmp_request has a length greater then 1. No matter what I pass to substr—1, 2, or bodypos—it always throws that error.  I'm using g++ on Unix.

Only interesting thing I can include is the string has multiple `"\r\n"`, including one `"\r\n\r\n"`.

In one cpp file:

```
std::string tmp_request, outRequest;

tmp_request = SS_Twitter->readData();
outRequest = SS_Twitter->parse(tmp_request);
```

In another:

```
 std::string parse(const std::string &request)
 {
  std::map<std::string,std::string> keyval;
  std::string outRequest;
  if(request[0]=='P')
  {
   if(request.find("register")!=std::string::npos)
   { //we have a register request
    size_t bodypos = request.find("username");
    if(bodypos==std::string::npos) 
    {
     HttpError(400,"Malformed HTTP POST request. Could not find key username.",request); 
    }
    else
    {
     std::string body = request.substr(bodypos);
     StringExplode(body,"&", "=",keyval);
     outRequest = "doing stuff";
    }

   }
```

Update:

```
std::string request2("P\r\nregister\r\nusername=hello\r\n\r\n");

std::string body = request2.substr(4);
```

That throws the same error. Now I know this is perfectly valid and correct code, but it's still throwing the error. 
//removed source link

Comment: Ok the code might not be that clean. But let's focus on the error please?

Comment: Whether or not something is a bug is rarely an opinion, when it comes to language. You should seriously doubt such a primitive function has a bug in the implementation, otherwise you get caught on the wrong thing. The fact you keep persisting your code is right and the implementation is somehow wrong will never solve your problem. Obvious, you have a logical error somewhere; you must **drop your assumptions** and start fresh.

Comment: Did you try to make your code clean and see if error appears again?  Maybe **that's** the reason.

Comment: This is wrong: `if(int(request.find("register"))!=std::string::npos)`.
`npos` is a `size_t`, an unsigned integer, while `int` is a signed integer. There is zero need to cast the result of `find`, and all you're doing is chopping the range in half. In fact, you'll *always enter this if-statement*, since an `int` likely can never reach the maximum value of a `size_t` (which is what `npos` is). If it's not the bug, it is *a* bug.

Comment: I would suggest logging the length of `request` and the value of `bodypos`.  That will tell you for certain whether you are seeing bad behavior from `substr` or whether you passed in bad arguments.

Comment: I did log the length and the value of request the value of bodypos. But it doesnt matter. Even if I pass substr(2), it will give me that error. The string length logged is always around 150.

Comment: In addition to my last comment, this is also wrong: `int bodypos = request.find("username");` Again, you're chopping the range in half, and will never enter the subsequent if-statement. I think this should incur a warning; turn your warning levels up to see.

Comment: I understand that some of you might thing that I have a preconceived idea that the error happens here, but I tested this all over the place, including in another program. Don't appreciate some of the negative remarks.

Comment: Ok I'll turn the warnings on and try with size_t bodypos. Update: same thing.

Comment: You should update your code, then, so people know what you've tried, and that the code is improved.

Comment: @Stanislav Palatnik: You shouldn't try "size_t bodypos". You should use `std::string::size_type bodypos`.

Comment: Ok I'll use size_type. Same error with that.

Comment: @Andrey: I'm pretty sure `std::string::size_type` is always `size_t`. It's the allocator's `size_type`, which is the default allocator, who's `size_type` is `size_t`.

Comment: The only time I've seen a mysterious "bug" in a string method (or in any other place where nothing could possibly be wrong), it had to do with unrelated undefined behavior elsewhere in the program.

Comment: By the way the \r\n is a red herring if you're thinking of it being compressed to \n - that's only for I/O (and only in certain circumstances, on some platforms, if you open files in text mode, on a new moon, etc.).

Comment: I'm not sure why people downvote this question. It's legitimate code with a legitimate problem, let's help the guy find it and clean up our answers so they help others who might have similar troubles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I modified your sample slightly to decrease amount of indentation used.
There are 5 "test cases" and none causes any problem. Could you please provide a sample request to reproduce the problem you're having.

EDIT: Forgot to mention: if this sample as it is (with commented-out bits) doesn't produce that error, your best bet is that you have a bug in your `StringExplode` function. You could post its source, to get a more helpful advice.

EDIT2:
In your `StringExplode`, change `results[tmpKey] = tmpKey.substr(found+1);` to `results[tmpKey] = tmpResult[i].substr(found+1);`. Change `int found` to `size_t found`, and remove all of `if (found > 0)`, that will fix your mysterious out_of_range. You were `substr`-ing a wrong string. Just in case, here's the code with a fix:

```
void StringExplode(std::string str, std::string objseparator, std::string keyseperator,
                   std::map <std::string, std::string> &results)
{
    size_t found;
    std::vector<std::string> tmpResult;
    found = str.find_first_of(objseparator);
    while(found != std::string::npos)
    {
        tmpResult.push_back(str.substr(0,found));
        str = str.substr(found+1);
        found = str.find_first_of(objseparator);
    }
    if(str.length() > 0)
    {
        tmpResult.push_back(str);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < tmpResult.size(); i++)
    {
        found = tmpResult[i].find_first_of(keyseperator);
        while(found != std::string::npos)
        {
                std::string tmpKey = tmpResult[i].substr(0, found);
                results[tmpKey] = tmpResult[i].substr(found+1);
                found = tmpResult[i].find_first_of(keyseperator, found + results[tmpKey].size());
        }

    }
}
```

Initial test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::string parse(const std::string &request)
{
    std::map<std::string,std::string> keyval;
    std::string outRequest;

    if(request[0] != 'P')
        return outRequest;

    if(request.find("register") == std::string::npos)
        return outRequest;

    //we have a register request
    size_t bodypos = request.find("username");
    if(bodypos==std::string::npos)
    {
        // HttpError(400,"Malformed HTTP POST request. Could not find key username.",request);
        // you said HttpError returns, so here's a return
        return outRequest;
    }

    std::string body = request.substr(bodypos);
    // StringExplode(body,"&", "=",keyval);
    outRequest = "doing stuff";

    return outRequest;
}

int main()
{

    std::string request("P\r\nregister\r\nusername=hello\r\n\r\n");
    std::cout << "[" << parse(request) << "]\n";

    request = "Pregisternusername=hello\r\n\r\n";
    std::cout << "[" << parse(request) << "]\n";

    request = "Pregisternusername=hello";
    std::cout << "[" << parse(request) << "]\n";

    request = "registernusername=hello";
    std::cout << "[" << parse(request) << "]\n";

    request = "";
    std::cout << "[" << parse(request) << "]\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs, predictably:

> [doing stuff]
>   [doing stuff]
>   [doing stuff]
>   []
>   []

Comment: I tried hardcoding that string string, and it gives me the same error. Not sure what's going on here :/
std::string request2("P\r\nregister\r\nusername=hello\r\n\r\n");
std::string body = request2.substr(4);

Comment: @Stanislav Palatnik, could you please post the source for `StringExplode`? Most likely the bug is there.

Comment: @Stanislav Can you try Dmitry's sample program with your compiler, using the same compiler and linker settings you're using for your other program? Maybe you have some problem with your environment.

Comment: @ Dmitry: I posted the complete code in the original post, but here is just the code for StringExplode : http://pastebin.ca/1795667

@ Curtis: Yes, Dmitry's code runs just fine.

Comment: @Stanislav Palatnik, check my EDIT2 in the answer, that should help.

Comment: Yup, the culprit was StringExplode! Thanks alot!

Comment: And, technically, it should be `::std::string::size_t`, not just `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it's failing on that `substr` and not on a `substr` call within the `HttpError` or `StringExplode` functions?  If you haven't already, you should run this through a debugger so that you can see exactly where it's throwing the exception.  Alternatively, you could add a:

```
std::cout << "calling substr" << std::endl;
```

line immediately before you call `substr`, and a similar line immediately afterwards, so that it would look like:

```
std::cout << "calling substr" << std::endl;
std::string body = request.substr(bodypos);
std::cout << "finished calling substr" << std::endl;

StringExplode(body,"&", "=",keyval);
outRequest = "doing stuff";
```

If that `substr` really is throwing the exception, then you'll know because the program will print "calling substr" without a matching "finished calling substr".  If it prints the pair of debug messages, though, or none at all, then something else is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

One fairly obvious thing wrong with your code:

```
int k = read(ns, buf, sizeof(buf)-1);
buf[k] = '\0';
```

You are not checking that read() succeeded - it returns -1 on failure which will cause all sorts of memory corruption problems if it occurs.

Also:

```
char * buf2 = const_cast<char *>(reply.c_str());
write(ns,buf2,sizeof(buf2));
```

You are taking the size of the pointer - you want the length of the output string:

```
write(ns, buf2, reply.size() );
```

And you should once again test that write succeeded and that it wrote as many bytes as you requested, though this shouldn't directly cause the substr() error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an else after

```
if(bodypos==std::string::npos)
{
    HttpError(...);
}
```

otherwise you are calling substr with bodypos = npos

Comment: No, because HttpError exits the program. I appreciate that advice, but the main reason I posted here is to find out why the substr is failing on Good strings.

Comment: @Stanislav Palatnik: The way to never find your error is to have a preconceived notion about what the error is.

Comment: Create a small test program that includes this code, then call it.  Set a breakpoint in the debugger and you'll see your mistake as you examine the variables as you step through code.

Comment: For the record, this answer was posted before the `else` existed, and (obviously) before we knew `HttpError` would exit the function. A valid but now irrelevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the (unsigned) type `std::string::size_type` instead of `int`.

Why are you casting the result of find to an int here:

`int(request.find("register"))!=std::string::npos`

Comment: std::string body = request.substr(bodypos); . Now back to me question :)

Comment: OK I've removed that question from my answer ("Where is the exception happening?") What about my second question: why are you casting to int? find returns an unsigned std::string::size_type

Comment: Hi Stanislav. Since I posted this answer you've edited your original question so the casts are now gone and you use size_t (not std::string::size_type, but you get the idea). Can you please confirm that you've also edited and tested your code, and the exception still occurs? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, it still occurs. I even hardcoded a test string and called substr, and it gave the same error.